# Parametrize test method in JUnit, not just whole class

Tags: java, junit, testng, data-driven-tests, testng-dataprovider

I would like to make a data-driven parametrized *method* in JUnit.

The examples that I see, parametrize the whole *class*.

E.g.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PrimeNumberCheckerTest {
```

However, I would like to parametrize a single test **method**, not the whole **class**.

In TestNG, something like that seems to look like this:

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {
   return new Object[][] {{2, true}, {6, false}, {19, true}, {22, false}, {23, true}};
}

// This test will run 4 times since we have 5 parameters defined
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void testPrimeNumberChecker(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) {
   System.out.println(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);
   Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult,
   primeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
}
```

**Is such a thing possible in JUnit?**

EDIT:

1. The most elegant/DRY way would be to have a single method-level annotation - which is what I'm hoping for.
2. I've found a library:

https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams

Example:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @Test
  @Parameters({"17, false", 
               "22, true" })
  public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
  }

}
```

The question still remains - is there something like that built into JUnit?

If not, then what is the closest built-in thing that would require the least amount of boiler-plate code or class-level contortions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@RunWith(Suite.class)` and `@Suite.SuiteClasses` to turn your outer class into a suite, and then have nested classes inside (defining the "sub-test-classes" of the suite), each with their own runner.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyFooTest.Individual.class, MyFooTest.WithParams.class})
public class MyFooTest {

  @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
  public static class WithParams {
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> primeNumbers() {
      ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testPrimeNumberChecker() {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }

  public static class Individual {
    @Test
    public void someOneOffTest() {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a lot of overhead though. I was hoping for a single method-level annotation... Like in here - https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams .

Comment: I've added those remarks into the "EDIT" section in my question as well.

Comment: I don't know offhand, but you _may_ be able to use the outer class itself as one of the subsuites: `@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyFooTest.class, MyFooTest.WithParams.class})`. That way only your parameterized tests need their own class, which at least cuts down on some of the overhead. It does feel like a lot, I agree. As far as I know, this is the best way with junit.

Answer (score 2):

TestNG is supposed to be able to [run JUnit tests](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#junit): so, you can use TestNG as runner and having old tests in JUnit + new/parameterized tests in TestNG.

From the documentation:

> TestNG can run JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests.  All you need to do is put
>   the JUnit jar file on the classpath, specify your JUnit test classes
>   in the testng.classNames property and set the testng.junit property to
>   true:
>
> ```
> <test name="Test1" junit="true">
>   <classes>
>     <!-- ... -->
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide some link which explains this (ideally, with a quote) ? Ideally pointing to real-world limitations of that setup. Then I will upvote :).

Comment: @KarolDepka Quote added, hope it will be enough